# Have NGINX reverse proxy on a virtual host

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, nginx-reverse-proxy

This might be a dumb question but I'm kind of new to NGINX, what I'm trying to do is this:

I want a virtual host to reverse proxy another service running in the same machine in port 1000, so I have a file called jg1 inside /sites-available folder and it looks like this

server {

```
server_name jg1.example;
listen 80;

access_log /var/log/nginx/jg1.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/jg1error.log;

location / {

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

}
```

}

As you see all I need is any browser in my computer respond when I hit http://jg1.example/ and show whatever I'm serving in http://localhost:10000 but it's not doing anything at all, btw the files jg1.log and jg1error.log do get created, I put that there just to see if nginx was actually reading the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh , Never Mind

I needed to add jg1.example to my /etc/hosts file as well duh! that made it work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).